# Find the temperature closest to 0

Tags: code-golf

In this exercise, you have to analyze records of temperature to find the closest to zero.

Write a program that prints the temperature closest to 0 among input data.

### Input

- N, the number of temperatures to analyse (optional). This will be nonzero.
- The N temperatures expressed as integers ranging from *-273 to 5526*.

### Output

Output the temperature closest to 0. If two temperatures are equally close, take the positive one. For instance, if the temperatures are -5 and 5, output 5.

### Example

```
Input

    5
    1 -2 -8 4 5

Output

    1
```

[This challenge is similar to this one on CodinGame, you can view the problem statement source here.](https://github.com/GlenDC/Codingame/blob/master/descriptions/temperatures.md)
Some modifications have been made to the text.

Comment: [Mirror of CodinGame problem statement](https://github.com/GlenDC/Codingame/blob/master/descriptions/temperatures.md). The site might not appreciate having solutions be made publicly available. I'm not sure what our current consensus is on problems taken from elsewhere. The problem isn't copy-pasted but some of your text is taken verbatim.

Comment: [Our current consensus is that it's on-topic, however attribution is required and probably should be edited into the post.](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/8949/46271)

Comment: I've edited in most of the original problem statement, it's probably best to include as much of the original text as possible. Also, if you could link directly to the problem (the interactive part), that would be great.

Comment: @Riker that edit has changed the problem being asked. The input formats are stricter and there is a special case for no input

Comment: @muddyfish better?

Comment: @Riker I think so

Comment: I made the count input optional.

Answer (score 10):

## [Python](https://docs.python.org/2/), 35 bytes

```python
lambda l:max((-x*x,x)for x in l)[1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#S7ON@Z@TmJuUkqiQY5WbWKGhoVuhVaFToZmWX6RQoZCZp5CjGW0Y@7@gKDOvRCFNI1rXSMdQR9cwVpMLWchIxyRW8z8A)

Narrowly beats:

```python
lambda l:min(l,key=lambda x:2*x*x-x)
lambda l:min(sorted(l)[::-1],key=abs)
```

Comment: why would you need to sort `l` in the second narrowly beaten one?

Comment: sorting it into descending order ensures the positive values come first and that `min` favours a positive smallest absolute value over a negative one (e.g. to prevent cases like `min([-1, 1],key=abs)`)

Answer (score 9):

### JavaScript (ES6), 33 bytes

```js
a=>a.reduce((m,n)=>n*n-n<m*m?n:m)
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

a=>a.reduce((m,n)=>n*n-n<m*m?n:m)

console.log(f([1, -2, -8, 4, 5]))
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 4 bytes

```
AÐṂṀ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@@94eMLDnU0Pdzb8P9z@qGmN@///0YY6CrpGQGyho2Cio2Aaq6MQDcKmQCHTWAA)

#### How it works

```
AÐṂṀ  Main link. Argument: A (array)

AÐṂ   Take all elements with minimal absolute value.
   Ṁ  Take the maximum. Yields 0 for an empty list.
```

Comment: You called ????

Comment: And [ADMM](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/admm.html) once again solves an minimization problem.

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog) (2), 5 or 2 bytes

```
~{≜∈}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@19X/ahzzqOOjtr//6N1TXVMdcx0dA2NYv9HAQA)

It wouldn't surprise me if there were a shorter solution along the lines of the Jelly or Pyke, but I like this one because it's so weird.

This is simply Brachylog's "find a list containing the input" operator `∈`, with an evaluation strategy `≜` that simply tries explicit values for integers until it finds one that works (and it happens to try in the order 0, 1, -1, 2, -2, 3, etc., which is surprisingly handy for this problem!), and inverted `~` (so that instead of trying to find an output list containing the input, it's trying to find an output contained in the input list). Unfortunately, inverting an evaluation strategy along with the value itself costs 2 bytes, so this doesn't beat the Jelly or Pyke solutions.

There's also a dubious 2-byte solution `≜∈`. All Brachylog predicates take exactly two arguments, which can each be inputs or outputs; by convention, the first is used as an input and the second is used as an output, but nothing actually enforces this, as the caller has complete control over the argument pattern used (and in Prolog, which Brachylog compiles to, there's no real convention about argument order). If a solution which takes input through its second argument and produces output through its first argument is acceptable, there's no requirement to do the inversion.

Comment: I had written a [meta posted](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/10276/acceptable-ways-of-using-input-and-output-variables-in-brachylog) about using Input as Output and vice-versa. My view is that it's kinda cheaty because `?` and `.` are not exactly symetrical in the code (notably, one is available on the left and one on the right). Though in a Prolog sense there is really nothing wrong with it.

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 31 bytes

```r
(l=scan())[order(abs(l),-l)][1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/XyPHtjg5MU9DUzM6vygltUgjMalYI0dTRzdHMzbaMPa/rqmC6X8A)

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 4 bytes

```
S_0^
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pyke#@x8cbxD3/7@uoY4CEOkaAbGFjoKJjoIpAA)

```
S_   - reversed(sorted(input))
  0^ - closest_to(^, 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>9</s> 6 bytes

```
0iSPYk
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@@@fGRwQmf3/f7SuqYJpLAA)

Thanks to Luis Mendo for pointing out there's actually a built-in for this in MATL, which is not present in MATLAB.

```
 i     % Take input
  S    % Sort
   P   % Reverse to have largest value first.
0   Yk % Closest value to zero, prioritizing the first match found
```

If you wish to follow the spec and also provide the number of temperatures to be read, this should be given as the second input, and will be silently discarded.

Comment: I think [`OiSPYk`](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@@@fGRwQmf3/f7SuqYJpLAA) works for 6 bytes

Comment: @LuisMendo Yes of course - no idea there was a built-in for that. I should really check the function table more often, perhaps highlight the things that ordinary MATLAB doesn't have.

Comment: Most MATL functions actually are taken from Matlab. There are only a few that don't correspond to Matlab functions

Comment: @LuisMendo I know - I usually write my MATL programs in MATLAB first because I find it more readable. But this is the second time I could have saved a lot with a built-in MATL-only function, so I should be careful not to write my programs too MATLAB-centric. Thanks for the tip, nonetheless.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
Max@*MinimalBy[Abs]
```

Composition of functions. Takes a list of integers as input and returns an integer as output.

Answer (score 2):

## C++14, 64 bytes

As unnamed lambda, expecting first argument to be like `vector<int>` and returing via reference parameter.

```cpp
[](auto L,int&r){r=L[0];for(int x:L)r=x*x<=r*r?r+x?x:x>r?x:r:r;}
```

Ungolfed and usage:

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

auto f=
[](auto L,int&r){ 
  r=L[0];
  for(int x:L)
    r = x*x<=r*r ?   //x is absolute less or equal
      r+x ?          //r==-x?
        x :          //no, just take x
        x>r ?        //take the positive one
          x :
          r      :
      r              //x was absolute greater, so keep r
    ;
}
;

int main(){
 std::vector<int> v = {5, 2, -2, -8, 4, -1, 1};
 int r;
 f(v,r);
 std::cout << r << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: That might be the most beautiful C++ one-liner I've ever seen

Comment: Using the `abs` built-in function for `int`s, you can replace the for loop content with `r=x*x<r*r|x==abs(r)?x:r;` which is 5 characters shorter

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) `-g`, 3 bytes

```
ña¼
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///DGxEN7/v@PNlUwVNA1UtC1UDBRMI3l4tJNBwA)

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 5 bytes

```
ña¼ v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn///DGxEN7FMr@/4/WNVUwjQUA)

Comment: Shouldn't the flag be added to the byte count? Especially since the answer doesn't work correctly without it?

Comment: @Nit [The recent consensus on Meta](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/61613) is that each invocation of a flag is considered a separate language. Thus, it is not counted towards the byte count. My submission is technically considered a Japt `-g` answer, not Japt.

Comment: You don't need the `1`.

Comment: @Shaggy Actually I don't think it's correct with or without the `1`: with, it fails on `[1, 0]` (giving `1`), without, it fails on `[-1, 1]` (giving `-1`). I believe `ña¼` may be the most correct way to do it.

Comment: @ETHproductions, I'd missed the part about outputting a postive integer in the case of a tie.

Comment: @ETHproductions Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 21 bytes

Added `+1` for `-p` since this challenge precedes "options don't count"

```perl
$G[abs]=$_}{$_+="@G"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/1/FPToxqTjWViW@tlolXttWycFd6f9/Cy4TYy5dEy5TIPyXX1CSmZ9X/F@3AAA)

Comment: This solution violates the condition "If two temperatures are equally close, take the positive one", it takes simply the last one instead.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 16 bytes

```
Îåà_Di¹{RDÄßs\kè
```

Explanation:

```
Î                 Push 0 and [implicit] input array
 å                For each element in the array, is it a 0?
  à               Find the greatest value (1 if there was a 0 in it, 0 otherwise)
   _              Negate boolean (0 -> 1, 1 -> 0)
    D             Duplicate
     i            If true, continue
      ¹           Push input
       R          Reversed
        D         Duplicated
         Ä        Absolute value
          ß       Greatest element
           s      Swap top two values in stack
            \     Delete topmost value in stack
             k    Index of greatest element in the array
              è   Value of the index in the input array
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3@47/DSwwviXTIP7awOcjnccnh@cUz24RX//0frmugo6BoBsYWOApBpCmQBKSMw0jWMBQA)

Not at short as I'd like, but at least it works.

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, 29 bytes

```
snd.maximum.map(\x->(-x^2,x))
```

Usage example: `snd.maximum.map(\x->(-x^2,x)) $ [1,-2,-8,4,5]`-> `1`.

Map each element `x` to a pair `(-x^2,x)`. Find the maximum and pick the 2nd element from the pair.

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, <s>63</s> 39 bytes

```java
s->s.reduce(1<<15,(r,i)->r*r-r<i*i?r:i)
```

Port from [*@Arnauld's* JavaScript answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/112039/52210). I couldn't find anything shorter..

-10 bytes converting Java 7 to 8,
and another -24 bytes thanks to *@OlivierGrégoire*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##rY/BbsIwDEDv/QofE5RE6zakCTqmHXcYF46IQ5YG5K4NyEmZEOq3d25BaPdxcBQn9vNzZY9WV@V372obI3xaDOcMAEPytLXOw3JIxwdwouJq0yasTUzkbWM@QlqNN4hyzoVdxkdMNqGDJQR4hT7qRTTky9Z5kRdFPlWCFEq9oAlpKnCCbzRD2c@H1kP7VXPrlXDcYwkNKwkegmG33lh50VmdYvKN2bfJHPgn1UEE89fvncie4lVTBP8zbLDenCFXoB85XhQ8K5hCJ@Vo/h/mALw7k0UfFOR3E3y6kbqs638B)

```java
s->                   // Method with IntStream parameter and int return-type
  s.reduce(1<<15,     //  Start `r` at 32768 (`32768^2` still fits inside a 32-bit integer)
     (r,i)->r*r-r<i*i?//  If `r^2 - r` is smaller than `i^2`:
       r              //   Leave `r` the same
      :               //  Else:
       i)             //   Replace the current `r` with `i`
                      //  Implicitly return the resulting `r`
```

Comment: Given that there was a dupe of this question recently, time to undust this one with [**39 bytes**](https://tio.run/##bVBNb4MwDL3zK3wMFaDSrhIqtFMvk3bYid2qHsxXlQ4CSkwnVPHbWZJSbVInxbHznp/t@IJX9C/F18SbrpUEF/0OeuJ1sIidJ6zqRU68Ff@SimSJjaHyGpWCD@QCbg5A12c1z0ERknbXlhfQaI6lJLk4H0@A8qxcmwrw2b4Lepv7JDpObdk9VLtJ@XsVyLLo85KFSRJuPIZe5vp7XKCPSbbIXnGbuVPs2FJXlEClIgU7EOU3cEHH0/F07wNw80MP9PFX2iIPXjzYjN6DXEcWnrl1pBNXKx0ZC5dLI4vM9asw5TQe/kG0eg3ze4ytq1rJ7CB2tO19wMfnAdJBUdkEbU9Bp7dDtWBVgF1XDwell8EOUuKg5l0zI3Zd9155dIyN0w8): `s->s.reduce(1<<15,(a,b)->a*a-a<b*b?a:b)`

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire Thanks. Was looking at this answer myself after it was closed as a dupe and noticed the `reduce` in Arnauld's JS answer, but you beat me to it (and I forgot about it again after come colleagues came asking questions ;) ).

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 81 bytes

two solutions: the first one requires an upper bound; both require all temperatures nonzero.

```php
for($r=9e9;$t=$argv[++$i];)abs($t)>abs($r)|abs($t)==abs($r)&&$t<$r?:$r=$t;echo$r;
for(;$t=$argv[++$i];)$r&&(abs($t)>abs($r)|abs($t)==abs($r)&&$t<$r)?:$r=$t;echo$r;
```

Run with `-r`, provide temperatures as command line arguments.

A lazy solution for **92 bytes**:

```php
$a=array_slice($argv,1);usort($a,function($a,$b){return abs($a)-abs($b)?:$b-$a;});echo$a[0];
```

defines a callback function for [`usort`](http://php.net/usort) and uses it on a slice of `$argv`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 15 bytes

```perl6
*.min:{.²,-$_}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPtfSy83M8@qWu/QJh1dlfja/9ZcxYmVCmkaKvGaCmn5RVwahjq6Rjq6FjomOqaaOlwaRgiujq4hSEQXSYWOoab1fwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 30 bytes

```javascript
a=>a.sort((a,b)=>a*a-a>b*b)[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z@TWqKQpmD7P9HWLlGvOL@oREMjUSdJE8jTStRNtEvSStKMNoj9n5yfV5yfk6qXk5@ukaYRbaijoGsExBY6CiY6CqaxmppcaCp0jcyNgZLGWKRMgRpNsGkxxW4USD1I/D8A)

Comment: Why `-a` is there?

Comment: Why fail `[-273, 43]`

Answer (score 1):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 28 bytes

```matlab
@(x)max(x(min(a=abs(x))==a))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzN7FCo0IjNzNPI9E2MakYKKJpa5uoqfk/TSNawVBB10hB10LBRME0VvM/AA)

Finds the smallest absolute value (`min(a=abs(x))`), then maps it back to which elements have that smallest absolute value in case of a tie (`x(...==a)`). Finally takes the maximum value of the results (`max(...)`) to ensure that in the event of a tie we get one result which is the positive one.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 209 Bytes

**Not really golfed**, but wanted to try to use mostly array functions, avoiding loops

[Try it Online!!](https://tio.run/##VY9BCoMwEEWv0kWQhEbQUjeN4kFCKGk6QVGMTEyhFM9u09guuhn@f/NgmLmbt7qd47RhMkvvpoOlRLMX0VI1hfAOl08XZGg0on5ePWg0HS14ou5Hx95AFDkZjmXk4csRHoAe6N7uvbVJcoyJPsYgS5VlxMlCxZPYUH3zO2V1imnD2oQuqYkVRg9J3sX/JcIScCIo1g1M5@I3Mq94fuJ5yc@84pViYnsD)

**Code**

`function f($a){$a[]=0;sort($a);$k=array_search(0,$a);$o=array_slice($a,$k+1);$u=array_reverse(array_diff($a,$o));if($u[1]&&$o[0]){$r=(abs($u[1])<abs($o[0]))?$u[1]:$o[0];}else{$r=($u[1])?$u[1]:$o[0];}return$r;}`

**Explanation**

```
function f($a){
$a[]=0;                                #As all nonzero values, 0 is pushed
sort($a);                              #Sorting the array
$k=array_search(0,$a);                 #Search where zero is
$o=array_slice($a,$k+1);               #Array with all values >0
$u=array_reverse(array_diff($a,$o));   #Array with all smaller than zero values
                                       #Array has ascending order so it gets reversed              
if($u[1]&&$o[0]){                      #if both are set we just compare the abs value
    $r=(abs($u[1])<abs($o[0]))?$u[1]:$o[0];
}else{
    $r=($u[1])?$u[1]:$o[0];            #al least one of them will allways be set
                                       #the first value is always returned
                                       #the 0 value on $u is not usetted that why $u[1]
}
return $r;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 29 bytes

```julia
x->sort(x,by=x->abs(x-.1))[1]
```

Sort by the absolute value of the temperature, but subtract .1 first to ensure positive temperatures always win.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59mm5Sanpn3v0LXrji/qESjQiep0hbISUwq1qjQ1TPU1Iw2jP2fmpfC5VCckV@ukKYRbaRjrGMSq4kmoKNrhCwGE/kPAA)

Comment: [25 bytes](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@59m@79C1644v6hEo0JXz1AnqdI2MalYMzpWW8/wP5dDcUZ@uUKaRrSRjrGOSawmmoCOrhGyGEzkPwA "Julia 0.6 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 5 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
{R0.x
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f@/OshAr@L//2hDHV0jHV0LHRMd01gA)

Or alternatively:

```
ÄWQÏà
```

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cEt44OH@wwv@/4821NE10tG10DHRMY0FAA)

**Explanation:**

```python
{      # Sort the (implicit) input-list lowest-to-highest
 R     # Reverse it to highest-to-lowest
  0.x  # Pop and push the item closest to 0
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)

Ä      # Get the absolute value of each in the (implicit) input-list
 W     # Push the minimum (without popping the list)
  Q    # Check which are equal to this minimum
   Ï   # Only keep the values in the (implicit) input-list at the truthy indices
    à  # Pop and push the maximum of the remaining values
       # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `h`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
ṠrþA
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPSVFMSVCOSVBMHIlQzMlQkVBJmZvb3Rlcj0maW5wdXQ9MSUyQy0yJTJDLTglMkM0JTJDNSZmbGFncz1o)

##### Explanation

```python
ṠrþA  # Implicit input
Ṡr    # Reverse-sort
  þA  # Sort by |x|
      # Take the first item
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `G`, 20 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 2.5 bytes

```
⁽ȧP
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJHPSIsIiIsIuKBvcinUCIsIiIsIls3LDIsLTIsOTEsNV0iXQ==)

Finds the minimum in the list by absolute value

Answer (score 0):

## Python, 62 bytes

```
def f(n):
    r=min(map(abs,n))
    return r if r in n else -r
```

It feels like there is a much simpler/shorter solution.

Comment: Can be shortened to: `def f(n):r=min(map(abs,n));return r if r in n else -r`

Answer (score 0):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), 74 bytes

```c
k,m;f(*i,n){for(k=*i;--n>0;k=(k*k>m*m||(k==-m&&k<m))?m:k)m=i[n];return k;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY5RS8QwEITf8yuWOzyyJdF6KIi51B9S@xDaRJc0W8n1HrTX314jiMI8zCwfO9PrfnT8tu2J@/EyeDid54Gm2/dmiyqZICtSjEuYsoy2IqM1N7WJVsYqNqlK12u5W50Oh3hKiC/pOWKy1HJnsp8vmSGadRP7wQdiDy5n9zl6lg5ByjN9@SkUj3d/vq07RBSCeIbkiCXCIgT8RGo7sLDoewVF@qigSD8peFDwuJpCfeTCBbm7GV55pyBIUv@VVP4W6HdWbcS6fQM)

Comment: [66 bytes](https://tio.run/##RY7BasMwEETv@oolIUUyUpuGFkIUpR/i@iBsKVnWWhfFOTSuv91VobQwhxl4zExr2t7zeVkjt/2tC3C8jh0Oj5fTQjrZKCvUrKY4ZEmuQmsMW3JU0SlV6YucM@mBjuktHUglhzU3NofxlhnIzotYdyEiB/A5@88@sPQKpLziPQyxePX05@tto5QSAnmE5JGlgkkI@IlYN@BgMs8aisxOQ5HZa3jR8DrbQn3kwkW52nTvvNIQJer/SSy9Bfq9tbViXr4B "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax/blob/master/docs/packed.md#packed-stax)

```
¢M║⌠§☺
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#p=9b4dbaf41501&i=[-4+5+4+-1+6+-8+1]&a=1)

#### Unpacked (6 bytes) and explanation

```
{|a}eoH
{  }e      Get all elements of array producing the minimum value from a block.
 |a          Absolute value.
     o     Sort ascending.
      H    Take last. Implicit print.
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 4 bytes

```
.m.a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xy9XL/H//2hDHV0jHV0LHVMdk1gA)

Explanation:

```
.m.a   #Code
.m.abQ #With implicit variables
.m   Q #Filter input list for values b with minimal value of the following:
  .ab  #Absolute value of b
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 31 bytes

```python
a=lambda q:sorted(q,key=abs)[0]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9E2JzE3KSVRodCqOL@oJDVFo1AnO7XSNjGpWDPaIPb/fwA)

Sorts items by absolute value and prints the first element.

Comment: This appears to fail if the list has two values with the same abs, and the negative first (like `[5,-2,2]` which should return `2`, but appears to return `-2`)

Comment: @brhfl I tested that and I got the positive number. I’ll try it again later today

Comment: Depends on the order in the original array. If `-2` is befor `2` it will print `-2` in the example of @mrhfl

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 56 bytes

```
DEF Z N,T
RSORT T
DIM V[N]ARYOP 2,V,T,T
SORT V,T?T[0]END
```

First, the input list is sorted, so the positive temperature will be chosen if there's a tie. Then each temperature is squared and stored in another array. The original array is sorted by this array, and the first item is printed.

Answer (score 0):

## [Avail](http://www.availlang.org/), 88 bytes

```
Method"f_«_»"is[c:[1..∞),t:integer*|quicksort a,b in t[1..c] by[|a-0.1|<|b-0.1|][1]]
```

Approximate deobfuscation:

```
Method "nearest to zero among first _ of «_»" is
[
    count : natural number,
    temps : integer*
|
    (quicksort a, b in temps[1..count] by [|a-0.1| < |b-0.1|])[1]
]
```

The [pattern syntax](http://www.availlang.org/about-avail/learn/quick-start.html#methods-message-pattern-language) in the method's name, `f_«_»`, will read the initial count as a natural number (whose type is abbreviated above as the range type `[1..∞)`) separate from the collected tuple of subsequent integers.

All that remains for the body is to [sort by a custom comparator](http://www.availlang.org/about-avail/documentation/stacks/library-documentation/avail/Avail/Foundation/Tuples/2169357673.html). Here we escape the need for a second-level comparison between `x` and `-x` by shifting the values slightly towards -∞.

Comment: Welcome to the site! Could you perhaps edit in a link to a site where others can test your submission, such as an online IDE?

Comment: I'm not sure an online sandbox is feasible quite yet (as I understand it, the expressiveness of the language requires different approaches to parsing and compilation), but point taken! Are there any site requirements for online reproducibility? 

I'm partaking as part of my learning, and to share what I've learned, not to "win" by any means.

Answer (score 0):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 53 bytes

```
Fd^sr[d*v]sA[ddlr+0=Asr]sR[dlAxlrlAx!<Rs_z0<M]dsMxlrp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcihDoAgEIDhVzmrFkAR2TBQbBQqQ4IXCY7bnPPl8cq3fz9efdFQFgVlkyClBU4zg1QzXyEYC1qbFfqBJ7WE45PJJ8TaJrF7apliwurf2pjBRSqfcCEjBV537z8)

We're going to use the register `r` to hold our final result, so the first thing we need to do is put a too-big number in there so that our first comparison always succeeds. I think the largest number we can push in two bytes is 165 (which is less than the required 5526), but `Fd^` gives us 15^15 which is plenty large. Macro `A`, `[d*v]sA` just does the square root of the square to give us absolute value.

Macro `R` handles putting a value into register `r`; we'll come back to it in a second. Macro `M`, `[dlAxlrlAx!<Rs_z0<M]dsMx` is our main macro. Duplicates the value on the stack, runs `A` to get ABS, then pushes the value in `r` and does the same. `!<R` checks to see if ABS(`r`) is <s>greater than or equal to</s> not less than ABS(top of stack), and if so it runs `R`. Since we had to leave behind a copy of the original top of stack for `R` to potentially use, we store to a useless register (`s_`) to pop it. `z0<M` just loops `M` until the stack is empty.

Macro `R`, `[ddlr+0=Asr]sR` duplicates the top of stack twice (we need to leave something behind for `M` to gobble up when we return). At this point we know that of the two absolute values, our new value is less than or equal to our old value. If they're equal, and one is positive and the other is negative, we always need the positive. Fortunately, knowing this we can easily check for the case of one being the inverse of the other by simply adding them and comparing to 0. If so, we run `A`, and no matter what else happened we know we're storing whatever is left in `r`.

After `M` has gone through the whole stack, we `l`oad `r` and `p`rint it.

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 19 bytes

```matlab
@(x)min(complex(x))
```

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0IzNzNPIzk/tyAntQLI0/yfphGta6hgqKBrpKBroWCiYBqr@R8A)

This exploits the fact that [`min`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/min.html) with complex input compares by absolute value, then by angle:

> For complex arguments, the magnitude of the elements are used for comparison. If the magnitudes are identical, then the results are ordered by phase angle in the range (-pi, pi].

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 171 bytes

```cs
using static System.Console;using System.Linq;class s{static void Main()=>Write(ReadLine()=="0"?0:ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).OrderBy(v=>v*(.1-v)).Last());}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RcpBC4IwGMbxe5/ixYtbsKGREIkGdTWKPHQe8yUGNmvvGkj02ZeQ0O3h9/w1CT04jPFFxt6AvPJGQzuSx7s8DJaGHsvfN2Nj7LPUvSICes99GEwHR2Us41V9dcYju6DqphQnqZIs2WXbv8j20RvPUkiniT1qz4z18qwcIZcn16HbjyxUdVgymYvAuWwUecZ5@YmxWOQgViA2sIbiCw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Headass](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Headass), 56 bytes

```
O{ON-)+E:U}.U+OUO[{UO(])P:N(+)+E:}.UO[U-O{UO(])P:N(+)E:}
```

[Try It Online!](https://dso.surge.sh/#@WyJoZWFkYXNzIiwiIiwiT3tPTi0pK0U6VX0uVStPVU9be1VPKF0pUDpOKCspK0U6fS5VT1tVLU97VU8oXSlQOk4oKylFOn0iLCIiLCI1XG40XG4zXG4yXG4tMVxuMSIsIiJd)

Increments / decrements a pair of counters until the value of the counter matches one of the inputs, with the positive counter having the first go (after 0 of course) to prioritize it over negative answers.

Positive counter hereby referred to as `+counter` and negative counter as `-counter`

Code breakdown:

```
O{ON-)+E:U}.  code block 0
O O           initialize both counters to 0
 {ON-)  :U}   put all inputs on the queue
      +E      then move to code block 1
           .  end code block

U+OUO[{UO(])P:N(+)+E:}.  code block 1 (-counter, starting at 0)
U+O                      increment +counter and put back on queue
   UO[                   store 0/-counter to r2 and put back on queue
      {       N(+)  :}   for each input
       UO                  enqueue input
         (])               if input is equal to 0/-counter
            P:               print value and halt
                  +E     then go to code block 2
                      .  end code block

UO[U-O{UO(])P:N(+)E:}    code block 2 (+counter, starting at 1)
UO[                      store +counter to r2 and put back on queue
   U-O                   decrement -counter and put back on queue
      {       N(+) :}    for each input
       UO                  enqueue input
         (])               if input is equal to +counter
            P:               print value and halt
                  E      then go to code block 1
```

I tried doing this with only 2 code blocks, 1 to init and one to handle both counters, but that meant that whichever value came first between positive and negative would win, which is wrong. There might be additional logic that could be added to such a loop which, combined with some more logic-golfing, could be shorter than this version, but i still think its pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

## [J-uby](https://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), 12 bytes

```ruby
:min_by+:abs
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700K740qXLBIjfbpaUlaboWa6xyM_Pikyq1rRKTiiFCmwoU3KKjDXV0jXR0LXRMdExjYyESCxZAaAA)

Answer (score 0):

## APL (Dyalog Unicode), 16 bytes

```
{⌈/⍵/⍨a=⌊/a←|¨⍵}
```

[Try it on TryAPL.org!](https://tryapl.org/?clear&q=%7B%E2%8C%88%2F%E2%8D%B5%2F%E2%8D%A8a%3D%E2%8C%8A%2Fa%E2%86%90%7C%C2%A8%E2%8D%B5%7D%2011%2044%2051%206%20%C2%AF10%20%C2%AF12%20%C2%AF5&run)