# Return closest to zero

Tags: code-golf, math

## Description :

You are given a string of numbers (positive and negative but not decimals) along with the number of entries like so.

Like so

`8 
'1 2 5 0 7 -9 12 -8'`

## Task :

Your job is to return the number closest to zero be it +ve or -ve. Your input will be separated by spaces only. You are free to return the answer in any way you like namely :

1. A string

   A float (Why would you though)

   An array (One digit array I guess)

   A number (preferred)

Since this is code golf the answer with the shortest will be the winner. I guess?

Have fun.

#### code snippets :

```js
console.log(`6
'1 -2 -8 4 3 5'`) // should return 1
console.log(`3
'-12 -5 -137'`) // should return -3
console.log(`8 
'1 2 5 0 7 -9 12 -8'`) // should return 0
```

#### Note :

This is my first attempt at this. Apologies in advance for any mistakes, do tell so I can correct them. Thanks

Comment: 1). updated my bad.

Comment: 2). Ok updated. I was not aware that is is a duplicate.

Comment: Can we take the input as a list of numbers?

Comment: Welcome to the site! As user202729 has mentioned, this is almost an exact duplicate of [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/112021/66833) existing challenge. Be sure to use the [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140/sandbox-for-proposed-challenges) to check if your challenges are duplicates and to catch any errors before posting. Also, make sure to read [Things to avoid when writing challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8047/things-to-avoid-when-writing-challenges) to see what to avoid and what to include.

Comment: Also -- we have a [sandbox for proposed challenges](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2140).

Comment: Sorry , just joined I was not aware of this. I will be sure to check before posting. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 41 bytes

```python
lambda n:min(map(abs,map(int,n.split())))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfbhvzPycxNyklUSHPKjczTyM3sUAjMalYB0Rn5pXo5OkVF@RklmhoAsH/giKgkEK6hpKhgpGCqYKBgrmCrqWCoZGCroWS5n8A)

Comment: oh i didn't see that this question had been closed while I was writing my answer....

Comment: Thanks for the answer , but since this already had an answer it was closed.